# How to merge rows with the same rowname into one

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
product<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac")
HD<-c("12","","","","")
HS<-c("","23","","","")
HR<-c("","","34","","")
HO<-c("","","","23","")
DF<-c("","","","","24")
store22<-data.frame(product,HD,HS,HR,HO,DF)



product HD HS HR HO DF
1      ab 12            
2      ab    23         
3      ab       34      
4      ac          23   
5      ac             24
```

I would likr to transform it in a way that I will keep only the unique values of the `product` and as a result bring the values in the same line like this:

```
product HD HS HR HO DF
1      ab 12 23 34      
2      ac          23 24
```

Comment: `store22 <- lapply(store22, as.character); aggregate(. ~ product, store22, function(x) as.character(x[x != ""]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `max` on character variables:

```
library(dplyr)

store22 %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  summarize_all(~max(as.character(.)))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  product HD    HS    HR    HO    DF   
  <fct>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ab      12    23    34    ""    ""   
2 ac      ""    ""    ""    23    24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
product<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac")
HD<-c("12","","","","")
HS<-c("","23","","","")
HR<-c("","","34","","")
HO<-c("","","","23","")
DF<-c("","","","","24")
store22<-data.frame(product,HD,HS,HR,HO,DF)

library(tidyverse)

store22 %>%
  mutate(product = as.character(product)) %>% # update to character variable
  gather(x,y,-product) %>%                    # reshape data
  filter(y != "") %>%                         # exclude rows where y is empty
  spread(x,y, fill="")                        # reshape again and replace NAs with empty values

#   product DF HD HO HR HS
# 1      ab    12    34 23
# 2      ac 24    23
```

Comment: You could use `spread( x, y, fill="")` and remove the mutate_all function which changes the NAs to empty values.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table`

```
data.table::setDT(store22)[,lapply(.SD,function(x){na.omit(as.numeric(as.character(x)))}),by="product"]

#   product HD HS HR HO DF
#1:      ab 12 23 34 NA NA
#2:      ac NA NA NA 23 24
```